# Multivariate Hypergeometic Distribution with overlapping events

Tags: multivariate-analysis, hypergeometric-distribution

I have a deck of **52 playing cards** and I play a game where I need a combination of specific card categories to make combos.

For example: I draw **5 cards as a sample hand** and I need exactly **1 Jack** and **1 Heart** to make a combo.

I can find the posibility of opening 1 random Jack and 1 random Heart by using the Multivariate Hypergeometic Distribution, by using these numbers:

- Hand Size n: 5
- Deck Size M: 52
- Success Jack: 1
- Possible Jacks: 4
- Success Hearts: 1
- Possible Hearts: 13

the result being 0,0020% (very low because I only want 1 of each).

The problem is that the Jack of Hearts is a possible success in both the Jack- and the Heart category, so he will appear as a success twice in the combinations.

1. What can I do to make sure this doesn't happen?
2. Is it possible to count the Jack of Hearts as a success in both categories, so I don't need an additional Heart or Jack?

//EDIT//

I think I get the hang of it, but need to test it out in practice.

I still draw **5 cards** as a sample hand from a **52 deck of cards**. But now I change the criteria, so I need

- 1 Heart (of 13 possible)
- 1 Jack (of 4 possible)
- 1 King or Queen (of 8 possible)
- 1 Clubs or Spade (of 26 possible)
- "+ 1 other"

As far as I can see, this would result in 24 succesful outcomes (4!. Correct me if I'm wrong). I'm not gonna write them all here, just wanna know if I use the right approach

One of the successful outcomes would consist of the following combination:

**1 Heart (not Jack, Queen or King)**, **1 Jack of Clubs or Spades**, **1 Queen of Heart** and **1 King or Queen of Clubs or Spades**.

$10\times 2\times 1\times 4 \times {52-10-1-31 \choose 1}=800$ (the -31 would be because they are all overlapping events at this point, except the Diamonds from A-10)

When I have calculated all 24 outcomes the probability would be calculated like this: $\frac{800+outcome2+outcome3+.....outcome'n}{2598960}$

Would this be correct?

Comment: Your result looks far too low. How did you calculate it?

Comment: I made a calculator in a Google Sheet. Trying to make a probablity calculator for trading card games (used playing cards for context). 

The formula imputs are calculated using different criteria, so I have to check if the imputs I have are consistent with the ones you have and check up on the ones that are different

Answer (score 0):

In total there are ${52 \choose 5}=2598960$ equally likely possibilities.

If you regard the Jack of Hearts as as a double success, the satisfactory cases are:

- Jack (not hearts) and Heart (not jack) and three "other" cards $3\times 12 \times {52-3-12-1 \choose 3}=257040$ ways
- Jack of Hearts and four "other" cards $1 \times {52-3-12-1 \choose 4}=58905$ ways

making the probability $\frac{257040+58905}{2598960}=\frac{177}{1456}\approx 0.121566$ which is rather higher than your answer

If you regard the Jack of Hearts as as a single success, the satisfactory cases are:

- Jack (not hearts) and Heart (not jack) and three "other" cards $3\times 12 \times {52-3-12-1 \choose 3}=257040$ ways
- Jack of Hearts and Heart (not jack) and three "other" cards $1\times 12 \times {52-3-12-1 \choose 3}=85680$ ways
- Jack (not hearts) and Jack of Hearts and three "other" cards $3\times 1 \times {52-3-12-1 \choose 3}=21420$ ways

making the probability $\frac{257040+85680+21420}{2598960}=\frac{51}{364}\approx 0.14011$ which is even higher

Comment: Hmm, looks like there is a mistake in my calculator then. Much appriciated buddy :)

Comment: "$3\times 12 \times {52-3-12-1 \choose 3}=257040$ ways "

Aren't you subtracting one too many times? Where did the -1 come from? :)

Comment: @LADD $3$ is the Jack (not hearts) and $12$ is the Hearts (not jack) and $1$ is the Jack of Hearts, so $52-3-12-1=36$ "other" cards

Comment: Ahh, I see it. Thanks :)

Comment: I edited the original post to test my understanding of the concept. If you could look at it, it would be very much appriciated.

Comment: @LADD Changing the question after it has an answer is generally frowned upon

Comment: Pardon. I wanted to post a reply, but the system told me to avoid asking for help, clarification, or responding to other answers, so I assumed the //EDIT// would be the way to go

Answer (score 0):

I think I get the hang of it, but need to test it out in practice.

I still draw **5 cards** as a sample hand from a **52 deck of cards**. But now I change the criteria, so I need

- 1 Heart (of 13 possible)
- 1 Jack (of 4 possible)
- 1 King or Queen (of 8 possible)
- 1 Clubs or Spade (of 26 possible)
- "+ 1 other"

As far as I can see, this would result in 24 succesful outcomes (4!. Correct me if I'm wrong). I'm not gonna write them all here, just wanna know if I use the right approach

One of the successful outcomes would consist of the following combination:

**1 Heart (not Jack, Queen or King)**, **1 Jack of Clubs or Spades**, **1 Queen of Heart** and **1 King or Queen of Clubs or Spades**.

$10\times 2\times 1\times 4 \times {52-10-1-31 \choose 1}=800$ (the -31 would be because they are all overlapping events at this point, except the Diamonds from A-10)

When I have calculated all 24 outcomes the probability would be calculated like this: $\frac{800+outcome2+outcome3+.....outcome'n}{2598960}$

Would this be correct?